# Run a schedule class every 1st of the month leaving weekends

Tags: scheduled-apex

I want to run a schedule class every 1st date of the month but if it is a saturday or a sunday I want to execute it on the coming monday.I have created a CRON expression that helps it to execute on 1st every month but I want to know how to skip weekends.

```
global class MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers implements schedulable
{
     public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 1 * ? *';

    global static String scheduleIt() {
        MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers sm = new MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers();
        return System.schedule('Monthly Reconciliation', CRON_EXP, sm);
    }

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
      EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00X55000000E6vb'];
      List<Profile> userProfile = [select id from profile where Name='CC - User Access'];
      OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'lcsalesforceadmin@mcmcg.com'];
      List<User> userList = new List<User>();
      userList = [Select id,IsActive from user where ProfileID IN:userProfile AND IsActive = TRUE];
      system.debug('userList-->'+userList);
      system.debug('userListsize-->'+userList.size());

      List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();

      if(userList.size() >0 && userList != Null)
      {
        for(User user : userList)
          {
                    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setTargetObjectId(userList[0].Id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mails.add(mail);
          }
                    Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can let job run on 1st every month and if it is satureday or Sunday you can reschedule to next Monday.

```
global class MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers implements schedulable
{
     public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 1 * ? *';

    global static String scheduleIt() {
        MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers sm = new MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers();
        return System.schedule('Monthly Reconciliation', CRON_EXP, sm);
    }

  global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
   {
      Date d = System.today();
      Datetime dt = (DateTime)d;
      String dayOfWeek = dt.format('EEEE');
      if(dayOfWeek!='Saturday' && dayOfWeek!='Sunday'){
          EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Id = '00X55000000E6vb'];
          List<Profile> userProfile = [select id from profile where Name='CC - User Access'];
          OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'lcsalesforceadmin@mcmcg.com'];
          List<User> userList = new List<User>();
          userList = [Select id,IsActive from user where ProfileID IN:userProfile AND IsActive = TRUE];
          system.debug('userList-->'+userList);
          system.debug('userListsize-->'+userList.size());

          List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> ();

          if(userList.size() >0 && userList != Null)
          {
            for(User user : userList)
              {
                        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                        mail.setTargetObjectId(userList[0].Id);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                        mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
                        mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                        mails.add(mail);
              }
                        Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
          }
       }
    else{
        String CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY='0 0 0 ';
        if(dayOfWeek=='Saturday'){
            CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY=CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY+'3';
            }
        else if(dayOfWeek=='Sunday'){
            CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY=CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY+'2';
            }
        CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY=CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY+' '+d.month() +' ?';
        MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers sm = new MonthlyNotificationtoProfileUsers();
        System.schedule('Monthly Reconciliation', CRON_EXP_NEXT_MONDAY, sm);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing if condition to check the dayOfWeek we can directly specify first monday of every month in cron expression. The cron is in format

Second - Minute - Hour - DayOfMonth - Month - DayOfWeek - Year(optional)

```
public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 ? * 2#1';
```

It means

- 0 second
- 0 minute
- 0 hour
- ? Any day of Month
- * Every Month
- 2#1 First(#1) Monday(2)

We can also write following Weekday expression for cron

```
public static String CRON_EXP = '0 0 0 ? * 1W';
```

The other symbols carry their usual meaning. `1W` means Weekday around 1st of every month. E.g. If 1 is Monday, it is taken as 1, if 1 is on Saturday, next monday is taken.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Cron expression that runs first weekday of every month at 10 am.

```
'0 0 10 1W * ? *'
```